# current time in informix stored proc

Tags: stored-procedures, informix

how to compare current time in informix stored proc ?

lets sat I hv a p_time param I want to compare this with a current time

like if p_time < current_time then

--do somehting

anyone?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Comparing dates only:

```
if (v_some_date < today) then
  --...
end if
```

Comparing dates with time:

```
if (v_some_dtime > current) then
  --...
end if
```

Comment: Something to keep in mind: `current` invoked inside a stored proc returns the value of the system clock of when the stored proc starts, not the time of when the statement containing `current` is executed. If you need precision you should retrieve the time using:

**`SELECT
    DBINFO('utc_to_datetime', sh_curtime)
INTO
    current_time
FROM
    sysmaster:sysshmvals;`**

as explained [here](http://informix-technology.blogspot.com.au/2009/08/current-time-really.html)